# Hide-show script on button click

Tags: javascript

I want to hide show my script when button is clicked currently I have a script that creates a `iframe` but its always visible what I want is to add a button to this script to attach functionality of **collapse** i.e
On click it **maximize/minimize the `iframe`**

**script**

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
  iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
  iframe.style.bottom='1%'
  iframe.style.right='1%'
  iframe.width = '315px';
  iframe.height = '380px';
</script>
```

Want to add button to this script along with `iframe` that could hide or show on click of button

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes why are you editing the height and not the visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating your html elements outside of javascript unless you need to. But here is an all javascript solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
  iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
  iframe.style.bottom='1%'
  iframe.style.right='1%'
  iframe.width = '315px';
  iframe.height = '380px';
  iframe.id = 'theIframe';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  var collapseButton = document.createElement('button');
  collapseButton.innerHTML = "Collapse!";
  collapseButton.onclick = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('theIframe');
    iframe.style['display'] = iframe.style['display'] === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
  document.body.appendChild(collapseButton);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v0coh8f9/

Also, JQuery provides .show(), .hide(), and .toggle() methods.

Comment: Worked perfectooooooo :p

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<button id="button">Toggle iFrame</button>
```

javascript

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
iframe.style.bottom='1%'
iframe.style.right='1%'
iframe.width = '315px';
iframe.height = '380px';
iframe.style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  iframe.style.display = iframe.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j24yed3v/